# How do I get the "results" object nested in the array "news" and map over it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

I'm trying to map over an array which is fetched using componentDidMount. However, I keep receiving this same error "Uncaught TypeError: this.state.news.map is not a function".

This is on componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
            "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=test"
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    news: data
                })
                console.log(data)
            })
    }
```

This is my function to map over the data

```
renderNews() {
        return this.state.news.map((a, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                {a.response.map((b, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <div key={i} className="newsEach">
                            <h3>{b.webTitle}</h3>
                            <ul className="newsInfoUl">
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">{b.type}</li>
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">
                                    {b.sectionName}
                                </li>
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">{b.pillarName}</li>
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">{b.webUrl}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ))
    }
```

Then I render out the data over here

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="newsWrapper">
                {/* <h3>{this.renderNews()}</h3> */}
                <h3>Hello</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Update #1
Here is the data that I got from console.log(data)

```
{response: {…}}
response:
currentPage: 1
orderBy: "newest"
pageSize: 10
pages: 211707
results: Array(10)
0: {id: "business/live/2019/may/31/markets-trump-shock-mexi…ffs-trade-war-china-brexit-ftse-100-business-live", type: "liveblog", sectionId: "business", sectionName: "Business", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:25:12Z", …}
1: {id: "football/2019/may/31/atletico-madrid-stadium-wanda…litano-champions-league-final-liverpool-tottenham", type: "article", sectionId: "football", sectionName: "Football", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:23:15Z", …}
2: {id: "tv-and-radio/2019/may/31/a-sinister-tale-from-the-minds-behind-dirty-john-podcasts-of-the-week", type: "article", sectionId: "tv-and-radio", sectionName: "Television & radio", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:12:02Z", …}
3: {id: "politics/2019/may/31/alastair-campbell-labour-expulsion-discrimination-appeal", type: "article", sectionId: "politics", sectionName: "Politics", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:11:22Z", …}
4: {id: "football/from-the-archive-blog/2019/may/31/womens-football-match-crouch-end-1895", type: "article", sectionId: "football", sectionName: "Football", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:00:27Z", …}
5: {id: "culture/2019/may/31/what-to-see-this-week-in-the-uk", type: "article", sectionId: "culture", sectionName: "Culture", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:00:27Z", …}
6: {id: "tv-and-radio/2019/may/31/when-they-see-us-review-netflix-ava-duvernay-central-park-five", type: "article", sectionId: "tv-and-radio", sectionName: "Television & radio", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:00:27Z", …}
7: {id: "music/2019/may/31/lee-scratch-perry-rainford-review-on-u-sound-records", type: "article", sectionId: "music", sectionName: "Music", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T08:00:27Z", …}
8: {id: "books/2019/may/31/mother-ship-francesca-segal-review", type: "article", sectionId: "books", sectionName: "Books", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T07:58:27Z", …}
9: {id: "football/2019/may/31/football-transfer-rumours-spurs-to-bid-for-wilfried-zaha", type: "article", sectionId: "football", sectionName: "Football", webPublicationDate: "2019-05-31T07:47:36Z", …}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
startIndex: 1
status: "ok"
total: 2117063
userTier: "developer"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Sorry I forgot to include this portion of my code which is what I initialize this.state.news with. Here it is

```
constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            news: []
        }

        this.renderNews = this.renderNews.bind(this)
    }
```

Comment: What is `this.state.news`?

Comment: You did a `console.log(data)` - may we see what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that render is called before the data is fetched. I would suggest adding a constructor to your component and initialize the news to an empty array:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    news: []
  };
}
```

And if you want to do it properly, you can add a loading property to your state:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    loading: true,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=test')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        news: data,
        loading: false,
      });
      console.log(data);
    });
}

render() {
  const { loading } = this.state;
  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1> {/* Or use a loading icon or gif */}
      ) : (
        <div className="newsWrapper">
          <h3>{this.renderNews()}</h3>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way your UI will be more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

This occours because at render time data is not yet ready.

You can do various things depending on your needs.

1º. Declare a default state like `state = { news: [] }` to be an empty array.

2º. Render some kind of Loading in render method like `if (!this.state.news.length) { return "Loading..." }`

I saw you have and array into each news item so you should also take control of it.

`state = { news: { data: [] } }`

Look, you are setting in setState `data` into news as a object property and then you tries to iterate over it   with map. You can't do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

during the render the news array is not present hence it is null, to solve this

```
renderNews() {
        const { news = [] } = this.state; // assign a default value
        return news.map((a, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                {a.response.map((b, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        <div key={i} className="newsEach">
                            <h3>{b.webTitle}</h3>
                            <ul className="newsInfoUl">
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">{b.type}</li>
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">
                                    {b.sectionName}
                                </li>
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">{b.pillarName}</li>
                                <li className="newsInfoEach">{b.webUrl}</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `this.state.news` is an object. In your `setState`, I think you are expecting `data.results` (which is an array) instead of just `data`.

```
this.setState({
  news: data.results,
  loading: false
});
```